# How to find a substring within a string and then print everything after the substring using a function

Tags: swift, string, substring

I keep running into a lot of problems while trying to implement my code. Im new to Swift and the syntax is very frustrating.

I cannot loop through the string. I MUST use a method/library function.

```
func findNextItem(from: String, in:[String]) -> String?{


return  nil
}

//FUNCTION MUST WORK WITH THE BELOW CODE
let bucketList = ["Travel to Antarctica", "Climb Mount Everest", "Run a 
marathon", "Write a book", "Build an iOS app"]
let item1 = findNextItem(from: "Write a book", in: bucketList)
let item2 = findNextItem(from: "Build an iOS app", in: bucketList)
let item3 = findNextItem(from: "Run a marathon", in: [])

print(item1!) // "Build an iOS app"
print(item2!) // "Travel to Antarctica"
print(item3)  // nil
```

Comment: Do you want to check that from  Parameter in are a supstring from in Parameter ?

Comment: Your question is ambiguous. Is item 3 `nil` because in order `Run a marathon` comes before `Write a book` or is it `nil` because the `in` parameter is empty? And there are no *substrings* in the question.

Comment: Are you looking for the array element following the given one (in cyclic order) in the array?